# Using php response to populate front end Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This should be a very easy question, but I cannot find the answer. I have a js file that is making an ajax request to a php file. i am then trying to use the response provided by php to update the front end, but the response is not in the correct format. I am getting back the whole `echo` statement when I look in the console. Pardon my ignorance here but I am quite new to php. I think there is an issue sending back an `a href` link and `br` in my php

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.container').html(data);
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $output = 'This is<br>a<br>test<br><a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><span>Test Here</span></a>';
    echo $output;
?>
```

When all this has successfully worked I want to change my html to:

```
<div class="container">
     This is<br>a<br>test<br><a href="https://stackoverflow.com"><span>Test Here</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a functioning web server configured to run php.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

When using `jQuery`'s `$.ajax` function you can use either of `{ success: function() {...} }` or `.done()` promise:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
    success:  function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.container').html(data);
    }
});
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
    success:  function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('.container').html(data);
    }
}).done(function( data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('.container').html(data);
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the php file, no? Not sure if it is returning the data as I want

Comment: Even if your PHP code returned the correct data - the jquery code wouldn't work. BTW, you should also add the `jquery` tag to your question.

Comment: I think there are issues sending a link back in the php

Comment: Regarding the php code - you can check the request and response in the developers tool bar.

Comment: No, there is no issue there. It's a normal string, you can do this.

Comment: i have checked the response in the network tools and it is showing `<?php echo ...?>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122317/discussion-between-dekel-and-phantom).